# How do you target direct descendants of :host in Angular using SCSS?

Tags: angular, sass

I have an angular component called `edge-button-bar`.  With view encapsulation turned off the following SCSS works as intended:

```
edge-button-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px 0;  // for when wrap occurs

  & > edge-button-bar {
    width: unset;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  & > * {
    min-width: auto !important;
  }

  & > *:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 15px;
  }

  & > button.mat-button:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
}
```

With view encapsulation enabled, I can't find the magic solution to using the :host psuedo-selector.  I tried the following (and other things):

```
:host {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px 0;  // for when wrap occurs

  & > edge-button-bar {
    width: unset;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  & > * {
    min-width: auto !important;
  }

  & > *:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 15px;
  }

  & > button.mat-button:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
}
```

Stackblitz example: https://angular-ivy-wvs5v1.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but I don't know if there's any side-effects.

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px 0; // for when wrap occurs

  & > :host {
    width: unset;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  & > * {
    min-width: auto !important;
  }

  & > *:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 15px;
  }

  & > button.mat-button:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
}
```